# How can one convert an expression to a string while keeping the quotation marks of strings that are part of the expression?

Tags: string-manipulation, conversion

How can I for example convert `{"a","b"}` to `"{\"a\",\"b\"}"`, so keeping the quotations marks.?
I tried `ToString[{"a","b"}]`, but this returns `"{a,b}"` in Mathematica 11.2.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ToString[{"a", "b"}, InputForm]
(*    "{\"a\", \"b\"}"    *)
```

(thanks @kglr for golfing!)

If you need to get rid of the space between the strings in the string (as per your specification), then use a `StringDelete[" "]` operator:

```
ToString[{"a", "b"}, InputForm] // StringDelete[" "]
(*    "{\"a\",\"b\"}"    *)
```

Comment: `StringDelete[" "]` wold also delete any `" "` inside the quotation marks, wouldn't it?

Comment: @rhermans yes you're right, may be a bad idea.

Comment: `ToString[{"a", "b"}, InputForm]` also works. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

`ToString[{"a", "b"} /. x_String :> ("\"" <> x <> "\"")]` seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

```
StringTemplate["{\"``\",\"``\"}"] @@ {"a", "b"}
```

> "{\"a\",\"b\"}"

Answer (score 0):

There is a short :) function to do this:

```
StringJoin @ Flatten @ ReplaceAll[RowBox -> List] @  
First @ First @ MathLink`CallFrontEnd @ UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket @ 
ToString @ InputForm @
{"a", "b"}
```

The idea is to create input form string with quoted characters, then to parse it as an input line (which will remove spaces) then take remaining strings and join them :)